# AWS API Gateway implicit deny not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have the following resource policy configured for AWS API gateway:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-north-1:XXX/*/*/some-api",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "some IP"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

According to the official documentation I expect other APIs to be implicitly denied. However that is not happening, I can call other APIs than `some-api` from any random IP address. What is wrong with the setup?

Documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-policy-language-overview.html

And then for the subject of "The Difference Between Denying by Default and Explicit Deny." it refers to:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html#AccessPolicyLanguage_Interplay

Comment: Did you re-deploy your stage?

Comment: @Marcin yes I did

Comment: "According to the official documentation " - do you have a link to that?

Comment: @Marcin updated the question with the documentation links

Comment: Did you [enable IAM authorization](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-authentication-api-gateway/) for your API?

Comment: @Marcin API authorization is based on lambda authorizer and not on IAM in this case